# Knockout observableArray not binding

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to bind an observableArray from an ajax server read but not able to bind it to the html.  The json data is returning but not sure how to parse or get it to bind.  I am new to Knockout.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type='text/javascript'     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

function SurnameViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Surnames = ko.observableArray();
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/GetSurnames/Name/CID",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "Name": "d", "CID": "17" }, // <==this is just a sample data
    processdata: true,
    success: function (result) {
    self.Surnames= ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data);
    alert(self.Surnames()); // <== able to see the json data

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Failure!");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
}


// Activates knockout.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new SurnameViewModel())
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Surnames</h2>
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Surname</th>
    </tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Surnames">
        <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Surnames().id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Surnames().homename"></td>

    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Json Data Returned from the alert

```
data: "[{"id":3,"homename":"DCosta"}]"
```

What am doing wrong here?

**Edit:  Working code**

This is what worked for me.

I change this

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, {}, self.Surnames);
```

to

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.Surnames);
```

and in the html from this

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: Surnames().id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Surnames().homename"></td>

</tr>
```

to this

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: homename"></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

In your view when using the `foreach` binding you are "inside" of the context of the array so you don't need to write out the array name (`Surnames()`) again:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Surnames">
   <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: homename"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

When you are getting back the data from the server you are overriding the `Surnames` array, the correct way of using the mapping plugin here:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, {} /* empty mapping options */, self.Surnames);
```

Or

```
self.Surnames(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data)());
```

Note the `()` in the above code, you need this because the `ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data)` will return an `ko.observableArray` without getting its underlaying value with the `()` you would end up with your `Surnames` containing another `ko.observableArray`

Comment: I tried bot methods am getting the in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: id
Message: id is not defined`  In there server call I am actually passing CID have updated my question

Comment: It does not matter what do you send to the server. It matters what you get back in your success callback: so please alert what you get back from the server `success: function (result) { alert(result) }` and post that. You can also try `fromJSON`: `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {} /* empty mapping options */, self.Surnames);`

Comment: @Adrian Here is a working jsfiddle created with using your sample data: `data: "[{"id":3,"homename":"DCosta"}]" ` http://jsfiddle.net/X7feb/

Comment: I used `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.Surnames);` and it worked.  The data that I get after adding alert(result.data) is `[{"id":3,"homename":"D\u0027Costa"}]`

Comment: do I need to add JSON.stringify as in your jsfiddle example?  Without that it worked

Comment: No, the `JSON.stringify` was needed only to work in JSFiddle. In your application it is not necessary.

Comment: works now editing my question to add the correct code that worked