# Knockout observables not binding and applyBindings firing twice

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I had earlier asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907967/knockout-observablearray-not-binding/) which worked in a html file.  Now I am trying to put the same in the ASP.NET webform but does not seem to work.

What happens here the first time the page loads ajax call fires which I do not want except when the cursor is moved away from the text box

On Blur I have a popup window that I want to show the data returned from the ajax call.  The data does not bind either.  What am I doing wrong here.

**My Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var self = this;
 function showPopUp() {
   var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
   var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
   var SName = document.getElementById("<%=txtSurname.ClientID%>").value
   document.getElementById("txtSurnameSearch").value = SName

   cvr.style.display = "block"
   dlg.style.display = "block"
   if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
   cvr.style.width = "1024"
   cvr.style.height = "100;"
   }
  this.SurnameViewModel(SName)  //<= here I pass the surname to the ViewModel

 }

 function closePopUp(el) {
   var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
   var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
   cvr.style.display = "none"
   dlg.style.display = "none"
   document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
 }


function SurnameViewModel(Surname) {
  var self = this;
  self.Surnames = ko.observableArray();
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/GetSurnames/Name/ChurchID",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "Name":Surname, "ChurchID": "17" },
    processdata: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.data);
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.Surnames);

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Failure!");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
}

  $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new SurnameViewModel());
 });
</script>
```

**My HTML**

```
<!-- Grey Background -->
<div id="cover"></div>
<!-- Surname Popup -->
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
My Dialog Content
<br /><input ID="txtSurnameSearch" type="text" />
<br /><input type="button" value="Submit" />
<br /><a href="#" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>

    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>  //<= just shows the header

    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Family Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Surnames">
    <tr>
       <td data-bind="value: id"></td>
       <td data-bind="value: homename"></td>
    </tr>    
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**TextBox where the onBlur is called:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="127px" class="txtboxes" placeholder="Last Name" onblur="showPopUp();" />
```

**JSON Data returned by the ajax call**

```
{"data":"[{\"id\":3,\"homename\":\"D\\u0027Costa\"}]"}
```

**Edit 1:**

If I hard code the values in the ajax call it seems to bind but still fires on page load

```
data: { "Name":"d", "ChurchID": "17" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view model your Ajax call is inline, not inside a method, so as an instance of its contstructed your AJAX gets fired off. See this code, we create a global variable to hold the instance of your model and then wrap the AJAX call into its on function (method) in your JS. Then you can just call the method on your instance when you need to in your popup code.

```
var self = this;
var model = new SurnameViewModel();

 function showPopUp() {
   var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
   var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
   var SName = document.getElementById("<%=txtSurname.ClientID%>").value
   document.getElementById("txtSurnameSearch").value = SName

   cvr.style.display = "block"
   dlg.style.display = "block"
   if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
   cvr.style.width = "1024"
   cvr.style.height = "100;"
   }
  model.GetSurname(SName)  //<= here I pass the surname to the ViewModel

 }

 function closePopUp(el) {
   var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
   var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
   cvr.style.display = "none"
   dlg.style.display = "none"
   document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
 }


function SurnameViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Surnames = ko.observableArray();
  self.GetSurname = function(Surname){

      $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/GetSurnames/Name/ChurchID",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "Name":Surname, "ChurchID": "17" },
        processdata: true,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.data);
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.Surnames);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Failure!");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
      });
  }
}

  $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(model);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: Cool let me know, also I think I made a spelling error on the second line FYI